# Django handling cookie gdpr

Tags: django, cookies, gdprconsentform

Quick question for django devs in Europe, how do you handle the cookie law in Europe in your django app?

I have seen a lot of solutions for an example cookiebot.com but I'm not sure if I want to use it. Also any other solution alternatives is appreciated.

All the best